# Hibernate spatial 5 can not insert data because of Invalid endian flag value encountered

Tags: spring-boot, postgis, hibernate-spatial

```
@Entity(name = "records")
data class RecordEntity(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val uid: Long = 0,
        @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)")
        val position: Point
) {
}
```

When I do insert operation, the error `Invalid endian flag value encountered` happened.

The position column's data type is `Geometry` at this moment.

I removed `@Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)")` this line, then it works fine. But another error `Invalid endian flag value encountered` when I do query with sql command `SELECT u FROM public.records u WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(u.position, ST_MakePoint(0.0, 0.0)) <= 18*1000`

The position column's data type became `bytea` after removing `@Column` line.

How should I do to make it works perfectly with Spring boot, Hibernate spatial 5 and PostGIS?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. What database, version and OS are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension, version 10; And Hibernate spatial version 5.4.5.Final

Comment: I've created a [bug ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13678) for this issue and will try to reproduce. But what Operating System are you using?

Comment: MacOS 0.15 (19A583), and PostgreSQL detail version is `postgresql-10.10-1-osx.dmg`

Comment: I recreate a new project, and now it's works fine.